# ng-repeat with JSON object not printing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller `chatController.js` and a `chat.html`

**chatController.js**

```
$scope.getMessage = function() {
    Chat.getMessage("C0RRZEDK4")
    .success(function(response) {
        console.log("getMessage: " + JSON.stringify(response));

        $scope.channel = response.messages;
    });
}
```

**chat.html**

```
<div ng-controller="ChatController">
    <form>
        <input ng-style="style(color)" type="text" ng-model="text" placeholder="text">
        <button ng-click="sendMessage()">Send!</button>
        <button ng-click="getMessage()">Get First Message!</button>

    </form>

    <li ng-repeat="msg in channel">
        <li>{{msg.text}}</li>

    </li>
```

*ng-app is specified in header elsewhere, the sendMessage() function works ok.

The problem is that when clicking getMessage in the GUI, the ng-repeat is not creating a list from the `channel` which is set with `response.messages` in the controller.

The response json looks like this:

```
{
    "ok":true,"messages": [
        {
        "type":"message",
        "user":"U0KTA20K0",
        "text":"123",
        "ts":"1457615693.000003"
        },

        {
         "user":"U0KTA20K0",
         "type":"message",
         "subtype":"channel_join",
         "text":"<@U0KTA20K0|julian_blair> has joined the 
channel","ts":"1457615234.000002"}
    ],

"has_more":false
}
```

Comment: Its an angular object I wrote passed into the controller next to the $scope service.

Comment: $scope.channel = (JSON.stringify(response)).messages

Comment: What does `<div>{{channel}}</div>` render on your page when added?

Comment: It prints : `[{"type":"message","user":"U0KTA20K0","text":"123","ts":"1457615693.000003"},{"user":"U0KTA20K0","type":"message","subtype":"channel_join","text":"<@U0KTA20K0|julian_blair> has joined the channel","ts":"1457615234.000002"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your `Chat.getMessage`execute inside `$digest` loop of angular. You can try this by this code:

```
Chat.getMessage("C0RRZEDK4")
    .success(function(response) {
        console.log("getMessage: " + JSON.stringify(response));

        $scope.channel = response.messages;
        $scope.$apply() // if it is inside $digest loop it will trigger an error
    });
```

if `$scope.$apply()` will not trigger error then your code executing outside of angular `$digest` loop.

Comment: I added $scope.$apply() and it triggered an error in the browser console: `Error: [$rootScope:inprog]` .

Comment: It seems like everything is ok )) try to define `$scope.channel = [];` as init value.

Comment: That fixed the issue!